# Akka Cluster Sharding - can different entities within the cluster communicate with each other?

Tags: akka, akka-cluster, akka-persistence

All materials on Cluster Sharding with Akka imply sending messages from outside the cluster to entities in the cluster. However, can entities (actors) in different sharding regions/shards of the same cluster communicate between each other? Is there some sample code available for this? (on how we send a message from one entity to another within a cluster)

Answer (score 2):

the short answer is "yes".

Let's elaborate:

You can view an `EntiryRef` is an `ActorRef` that's known to be sharded, so what you need, in any case, is a mechanism to obtain that `entityRef`. That mechanism is the `ClusterSharding` extension. So using:

```scala
val sharding = ClusterSharding(system)
```

you obtain the sharding extension which you can then use:

```scala
val counterOne: EntityRef[Counter.Command] = sharding.entityRefFor(TypeKey, "counter-1")
```

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer, I thought that I would have had to resort to using a message broker for such data interchange ... Direct communications between entities (of different types) in the shared cluster would help in my use case.

Comment: I see that you are a new contributor.  Could you kindly accept ignasi's answer?